# Selecting Users signed up in past 30 days and in past 7 days in one efficient query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query that selects the number of user signups in the past 30 days:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS UserCount30
FROM
  User
WHERE
  User.UserDateCreated > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Then I have this query that selects the number of users that signed up in the past 7 days

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS UserCount7
FROM
  User
WHERE
  User.UserDateCreated > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Ideally, these are all going to be part of one larger query.  How could I get both of these values in one efficient query that preferably does not use subqueries.

Comment: I take it that you're considering users who have signed-up in the last 7 days to be a subset of users who have signed-up in the last 30 days?  (you want them to be included in both counts?)

Comment: @dave Of course.  A user that signed up in the last 7 days is also a user that signed up in the last 30.

Answer (score 6):

Do the pull for 30 days and count(*) on that.  Then do a sum and as the expr in sum have an if statement return a 1 if its within 7 days or 0 if it isn't.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount30, 
       SUM(if((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) < User.UserDateCreated) 1 else 0)
  FROM USER
 WHERE User.UserDateCreated > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use subqueries? Because of 'all subqueries are slow' myth?

Here

```
SELECT
 u1.cnt AS UserCount30,
 u2.cnt AS UserCount7
FROM (SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  User
WHERE
  User.UserDateCreated > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
) AS c1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  User
WHERE
  User.UserDateCreated > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
) AS c2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   SUM(if((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)< User.UserDateCreated) 1 else 0) AS Last30, 
   SUM(if((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)< User.UserDateCreated) 1 else 0) AS Last7
FROM 
   USER
```

I liked coffeepac's answer, but changed just a little (easier to read / understand what it's doing this way, IMHO).

I'm not a mySQL guy, but one thing I'd be careful of is if UserDateCreated is a "date/time" field like Sql-Server uses.  In that case, it's better to strip the time off before you do a logical (<,>,=,...) comparrision.

Comment: In this one, won't the Last7s be counted twice?  I.e., they are signed up within the last 30 and within the last 7.

Comment: Yes -- I verified that with @bball -- any user who has signed-up in the last 7 days should be in both counts.